# Need help: Animated Rig not working in rendered animation

Tags: animation, rigging, octane-render-engine

I rigged and animated, trough keyframes, in pose mode, the toes of a foot.

In the viewport, also in rendered view, everything looks just fine and the foot animates correctly.

However, when i hit "render animation", the rigging animation doesn't show up. Everything animates correctly, the camera and all the rest except for the foot's rigging.

I'm using blender octane edition (free tier) 3.1.2

Can anyone help? it would be life-saving!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try if it works with standard Eevee or Cycles render, on a standard Blender build?

Comment: Hello, no I didn't cause I need to render it in octane.. All the other scenes are rendered in octane

Comment: Just try a little piece, only for understanding where lies the problem.